# Using code defined in .js file

Tags: javascript

Surely obvious but wanna be sure after some surprises in IE.

I've some js code defined in a .js file (nothing surprising here...).

I'd like to know what's the best practice to use this code (raw js, no framework here).

1. Is it valid to:

   - insert `window.onload = foo;` inside the .js file
   - define `foo` in the html (`foo` containing objects defined in the file).
2. Is it still possible to define other `window.onload` in the html?

If not, what's the best practice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more fool-proof way would be to use

```
window.onload = function() { foo(); };
```

and that is because, if window.onload = foo, is reached before the Foo is declared (within the html document) it will be registered as window.onload = undefined; And nothing will happen.

wrapping foo in a closure, you are ensuring that when the page is loaded, it will try to find and call foo, which will by then be already declared

(The above scenario won't happen if window.onload is ran on dom ready or below the declaration of foo)

Comment: thanks for this, is it good practice to insert `window.onload` in external file?

Comment: If that is the event you are after and not for example the dom content loaded one. (window.onload is called when all the assets of the page have loaded, including images etc. Whereas DomContentLoaded when the html "dom-tree" of the page is ready). Then yes there is nothing wrong with it. Just keep in mind that if you want to add/qeue functions you will need to do something like this http://jsdo.it/Pantelis/kjwJ (since setting the .onload property overwrites the previous value)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to have `window.onload = func;` anywhere, but the last will overwrite all others. In case you might have more than one handler, attach the event using the proper syntax per browser.

Comment: It's also answered by the word *anywhere* - this also includes external JS file. The JavaScript "compiler" won't start compiling before all the code is available, so you don't have to worry about server load or delay - such thing will affect the whole JS load time, and for this there exists "lazy loading" of JS files - using such technique, one indeed lose the `onload` event.

Answer (score 0):

.js code will be "injected" into the document and treated the same as if it were inline.

Comment: I know that, my question is more about delay when loading js file. You can't use code straight when defined in external file.